# $ \frac{1}{0^{-}}+\frac{1}{0^{+}}=0 ? $

Tags: calculus, limits

Let's take the function $f(x)=x^{-1}$. My question is this: Is the sum $$\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}$$ as $a\rightarrow 0$ near the point $x=0$ equal 0? And how would I proove this anytime I encounter this kind of limit? How would this work with derivatives or integrals?

Comment: What does "as $a \to 0$  near the point $x=0$" mean? The limit is $\frac{2}{x}$ if $x \ne 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: $\lim_{a\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0} f(x-a)+f(x+a)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{a\to 0} f(x-a)+f(x+a)$ does not exist.

Comment: BTW the answer to the question in the title is "No". For instance,
$$\frac{1}{-1/n} + \frac{1}{1/n^2} \to \infty.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantity you seem to be asking about is $$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}$$ "near" $x=0.$ Well, assuming that $x$ is not $0,$ then this is simply $$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}=\frac1x+\frac1x=\frac2x$$ by continuity. Now, if $x=0,$ then we have $$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}=\lim_{a\to 0}-\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a}=\lim_{a\to 0}0=0.$$

This is a good example of why we can't always interchange limits, since $$\lim_{a\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}=0,$$ but $$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}$$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what limit are you evaluating first.

First, $\lim_{a\to 0}(\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}))=\lim_{a\to 0}0=0$, but, on the other hand, you have $\lim_{x\to 0}(\lim_{a\to 0} (\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x+a}))=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2}{x}$ and this limit does not exist. So, the order of taking these "iterated" limits in a two variable (or generally, $n$-variable) problems is important.

Comment: Oh, Cameron did it already.